# Removing [ and ] from xmlhttp array javascript variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, xmlhttprequest

I have seen many of these examples but I just cant seem to get it to work.

I have `["15"]`, and want to remove the `["]` and just leave the number.

I have removed the `"` using

```
pickupsuburbcode = pickupsuburbcode.replace(/['"]/g, '');
```

so now I have [15]

but now I am stuck.

Comment: `.replace(/['"\]\[]/g, ''); `

Comment: thanks buddy that worked

Comment: assign it to a variable and use index - http://codepen.io/pen/  Hope this works for you :)

Comment: pickupsuburbcode[0] will get you only 15 without quotes or brackets

Comment: Naga, because this is a xmlhttp array, this will only return [

Comment: Naga, more explanation to my previous comment.

pickupsuburbcode = xmlhttp3.responseText;

Comment: oh k @Mikey3Strings, if  xmlhttp3.responseText is going to be something like ["15"], then pickupsuburbcode[0] this works without regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include `[` and `]` inside your regex character class, with proper escaping

```
'["15"]'.replace(/['"[\]]/g, ''); // '15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking about this as removing the `[` and `"`, think about it as picking out the numbers.

```js
var match = '["15"]'.match(/\d+/);

console.log(match[0]);
```

But why are you trying to do this? If this is JSON, don't try to parse it using regexp. Instead, just parse it and extract what you want:

```js
var result = JSON.parse('["15"]');

console.log(Number(result[0]));
```